# Hot Swappable Index in Sitecore 7.2 with Lucene

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I was experimenting about the new Sitecore 7.2 functionality **SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex**

Apparently, this functionality allow me to access in a **readonly** mode my Index meanwhile I am rebuilding the index.

Is there any way to have a full operational index (not read-only) meanwhile I am rebuilding the index?

The test that I am performing is the following one:

1) Rebuild a custom index with 30k items (it takes 30 sec)

2) meanwhile the index is rebuilding: Add a Sitecore Items (via code)

3) meanwhile the index rebuilding: access the custom index (via code) to get the count of items

4) after the index completed the rebuild: access the custom index (via code) to get the count of items

In step 3 it returns the original item counts 30000 
In step 4 it returns the updated  item counts 30001

thanks for the help
Stelio

Comment: What do you mean "full operational index (not read-only)"? You can continue to add items to Sitecore while the index is being rebuilt, I assume you want to add any item added _during_ the index rebuild?

Comment: I would like to get returned the items that I have added/updated to the search results... At the moment during the rebuild, it is returning a "snapshot" of what it was in the index before starting the rebuild procedure

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. You should look at the different Indexing strategies and making use of Workflow to ensure your item is Published. I am assuming you are creating the Item through Content Editor and from code.

Comment: Have you seen the blog post http://blog.eldblom.dk/2014/07/31/avoiding-downtime-while-rebuilding-your-lucene-search-indexes-in-sitecore-asp-net-cms/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that this will be possible. Conceptually speaking, Sitecore is essentially a software that makes databases more user-friendly and defines a structure that both technical and non-technical persons can understand and follow. What you are talking about goes against the concept of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), database [locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(database)) and [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). I have commented with more technical (database) annotations on your steps, inline, below:

1. Rebuild a custom index... - *Place a lock on the items in the database and start transaction*
2. meanwhile ...: add a sitecore item... - *A separate transaction running against the items, though not affecting the locked set that the transaction started in step 1 is using*
3. meanwhile ...: access the custom... - *Another transaction runs after the transaction in step 2, thus including the count of all items (including the locked set and the newly added item)*
4. after the index completed... - *Transaction 1 completed and lock released; Get count of items from custom index returns a different count than count of items if not counted from the index (the latter is greater, as a new item was added)*

As such, step 3 returns the new count of items and step 4 returns the original.

Comment: And Step 5 would be to rebuild the index again, thus adding in your newly added item and getting the new correct count. Of course, you could use a different [Indexing Strategy](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/04/Sitecore-7-Index-Update-Strategies.aspx) to ensure incremental updates so a full rebuild is not required.

Comment: Hi Zachary, thanks for answering... Your answer does not make much sense to me... more specifically I cannot understand how you can apply lock and transactions to Sitecore Items and how this would be related to the Lucene index problem. Have you read the documentation of SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex? Are you familiar with lucene indexing concepts? About the fact of using a different strategy to avoid a full index rebuild, that's not the purpose of the question....

Comment: Hi @Stelio - As I said in my answer, I believe that what you are looking for is not possible. Sitecore provides a visual representation of a strictly structured database. Indexing/adding/counting items, when examined at a low-level, are nothing more than database transactions. My answer is meant to guide you through your problem at a low-level, so as to demonstrate why I believe that what you are looking for is impossible. Regardless of whether or not what you were trying to do is possible, your expected results are still unreachable, as the result of step 3 and step 4 are swapped.

Comment: As jammykam mentioned in his comment, in order to read the full count of items from the newly rebuilt index, you would have to rebuild it again. The bottom line is if you are currently rebuilding the index and you add an item while the index is rebuilding that item will not be in the index.

Comment: HI Zachary, Lucene index does not involve SQL at all... it is based on the file system, SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex just create a different folder to rebuild the index, the problem is that events from Sitecore history table are not updating the "read-only" index... nothing to do with the transactions and locks that you are talking about.,,

Comment: The addition/removal of items is 100% database. I made a point to include the word "conceptually" in my solution, as Lucene still runs against the database and acts much the same as a database index would. Either way, Lucene runs against the database, which means that there IS a transaction happening on the database, thus meaning that there IS a lock on the database when said transaction is processing. It has everything to do with transaction and locks. Try the steps that I described and see that the result is exactly as I noted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of the changes, which happened during the index rebuild you could use the IntervalAsynchronousStrategy as your index rebuild strategy.

```
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
      <intervalAsyncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <param desc="database">master</param>
        <param desc="interval">00:00:05</param>
        <!-- whether full index rebuild should be triggered if the number of items in history engine exceeds ContentSearch.FullRebuildItemCountThreshold -->
        <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
      </intervalAsyncMaster>
    </strategies>
```

This reads through the History table and updates your index accordingly.
If you check the Sitecore implementation of this class, you can see that it handles the rebuilding event. If rebuilding is running it doesn't do anything and waits for the next time it is scheduled, and if the rebuild has finished it collects the entries from History table and applies them to the index. See Run method of the class:

```
...
    if (IndexCustodian.IsIndexingPaused(this.index))
    {
        CrawlingLog.Log.Debug(string.Format("[Index={0}] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.", this.index.Name), null);
    }
    else if (IndexCustodian.IsRebuilding(this.index))
    {
        CrawlingLog.Log.Debug(string.Format("[Index={0}] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Index is being built at the moment.", this.index.Name), null);
    }
    else
    {
        CrawlingLog.Log.Debug(string.Format("[Index={0}] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy executing.", this.index.Name), null);
        HistoryEntry[] history = HistoryReader.GetHistory(this.Database, this.index.Summary.LastUpdated); 

...
```